# Row BGCOLOR Sets for ENTIRE Dynamic Browse, not Just 1 Row

Tags: browser, dynamic, openedge

Using the ROW-DISPLAY trigger when creating a dynamic OpenEdge browse.  The problem is, when the data is displayed, all rows have the BGCOLOR determined by the data buffer's content of the LAST row only.  Never had this problem with a static browse.

Browse code looks like this:

```
CREATE BROWSE l-browse-wh IN WIDGET-POOL "pool"

  ASSIGN X = 1
         Y = l-browse-y
         FONT = INT(get-fn("browsedat-fnt"))
         HEIGHT-PIXELS = l-h
         WIDTH-PIXELS = FRAME f-data:WIDTH-PIXELS - 20 
         QUERY = hQuery
         HIDDEN = FALSE
         ROW-HEIGHT-CHARS = 0.67
         READ-ONLY = FALSE
         ROW-MARKERS = FALSE
         SEPARATORS = TRUE
         COLUMN-RESIZABLE = TRUE
         COLUMN-SCROLLING = TRUE
         FIT-LAST-COLUMN = FALSE 
         SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL = FALSE
         FRAME = FRAME f-data:HANDLE
         VISIBLE = TRUE
         SENSITIVE = TRUE
  TRIGGERS:
  ON ROW-DISPLAY
     PERSISTENT RUN row-color-ip IN THIS-PROCEDURE.
  END TRIGGERS.

PROCEDURE row-color-ip:

DEF VAR l-bgcolor AS INT NO-UNDO.

IF tt-sold.t-exclude-sw  /* <-- always uses value from last browse row */
    THEN ASSIGN l-bgcolor = 8.
    ELSE ASSIGN l-bgcolor = 15.

FOR EACH tt-col-handles
    NO-LOCK:
    ASSIGN tt-col-handles.t-wh:BGCOLOR = l-bgcolor.
END.   /* of "FOR EACH tt-col-handles" */
END PROCEDURE.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's something with your code (the part you're not showing). I used 10.2B Windows and replicated your code, filling the blanks. This little program alternates the colors, as I expected.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE l-browse-wh AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
define temp-table tt-sold
field cod as int
field name as char
field t-exclude-sw as logical.

create query hQuery.
hQuery:set-buffers(temp-table tt-sold:default-buffer-handle).
hQuery:query-prepare('for each tt-sold').

define temp-table tt-col-handles
field i as int
field t-wh as handle.
create widget-pool 'pool'.
define frame f-data with size 75 by 20.
CREATE BROWSE l-browse-wh IN WIDGET-POOL "pool"
  ASSIGN X = 1
         width = 60
         height = 10
         QUERY = hQuery
         HIDDEN = FALSE
         ROW-HEIGHT-CHARS = 0.67
         READ-ONLY = FALSE
         ROW-MARKERS = FALSE
         SEPARATORS = TRUE
         COLUMN-RESIZABLE = TRUE
         COLUMN-SCROLLING = TRUE
         FIT-LAST-COLUMN = FALSE 
         SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL = FALSE
         FRAME = FRAME f-data:HANDLE
         VISIBLE = TRUE
         SENSITIVE = TRUE
  TRIGGERS:
  ON ROW-DISPLAY
     PERSISTENT RUN row-color-ip IN THIS-PROCEDURE.
  END TRIGGERS.

create tt-sold.
assign tt-sold.cod = 1 tt-sold.name = 'ABC' tt-sold.t-exclude-sw = yes.
create tt-sold.
assign tt-sold.cod = 2 tt-sold.name = 'DEF' tt-sold.t-exclude-sw = no.
create tt-sold.
assign tt-sold.cod = 3 tt-sold.name = 'GHI' tt-sold.t-exclude-sw = yes.
create tt-sold.
assign tt-sold.cod = 4 tt-sold.name = 'JKL' tt-sold.t-exclude-sw = no.



create tt-col-handles.
assign tt-col-handles.i = 1 tt-col-handles.t-wh = l-browse-wh:add-like-column('tt-sold.cod').
create tt-col-handles.
assign tt-col-handles.i = 2 tt-col-handles.t-wh = l-browse-wh:add-like-column('tt-sold.name').
create tt-col-handles.
assign tt-col-handles.i = 3 tt-col-handles.t-wh = l-browse-wh:add-like-column('tt-sold.t-exclude-sw').
hQuery:query-open(). 
l-browse-wh:refresh().
wait-for close of this-procedure.
PROCEDURE row-color-ip:

DEF VAR l-bgcolor AS INT NO-UNDO.

IF tt-sold.t-exclude-sw  /* <-- always uses value from last browse row */
    THEN ASSIGN l-bgcolor = 8.
    ELSE ASSIGN l-bgcolor = 15.

FOR EACH tt-col-handles
    NO-LOCK:
    ASSIGN tt-col-handles.t-wh:BGCOLOR = l-bgcolor.
END.   /* of "FOR EACH tt-col-handles" */
END PROCEDURE.
```

I apologize for the large chunk, but I couldn't just put my finger on where you're going wrong. Maybe this example will help you in some way. Hope it helps!